# fragment navigation extension function does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have created this extension function for navigating between fragments which is pretty straight forward but somehow it's not working. it's not doing anything and nothing changes when I click the button. I think the problem is with `this@navigate` argument but I don't see why that should be a problem.

```
fun Fragment.navigate(): Int? {
    return fragmentManager?.run {
        beginTransaction()
            .replace(
                R.id.my_container,
                this@navigate,
                this@navigate::class.simpleName
            )
            .commit() 
    }
}
```

and the usage is like this

```
class TestTwoFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_test_two) {
   
    ....

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        goto_three.setOnClickListener {
            TestThreeFragment
                .newInstance()
                .navigate()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I meant it's not doing anything at all, nothing changes when I click the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `fragmentManager` of the new fragment which will be `null` if the fragment hasn't been added yet, like in your case. Since you're using `?.run`, nothing happens and the method returns `null`.

Consider adding a fragment manager parameter to your method:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.navigate(fm: FragmentManager): Int? {
    return fm.run {
        beginTransaction()
            .replace(
                R.id.my_container,
                this@navigate,
                this@navigate::class.simpleName
            )
            .commit() 
    }
}
```

And then:

```kotlin
TestThreeFragment
    .newInstance()
    .navigate(getParentFragmentManager())
```